# Need 2 buttons that will read the JSON's 1st and 2th value without saying its key

Tags: java, android, json, path, key

How I want th app to work:
As you can see in the photo attached, evey obj has 4 paths.
I want th user to read first 2 values (considring we ar in obj 1, the user reads a1 and b1 on screen) and after reading them he will have to choose its next path, either 2 or 5 (considering obj 1, th very first one). After he chooses 2 or 5, he will be again presented with values (a2 and b2, if he choose path 2 considring the photo attached) and he will have to make again a choice (betwen 3 and 4 considring th photo attached) and so on.
I want 2 things.

1. Read th current obj first 2 values (which will be a and b) WITHOUT writing its key (not "String a = object2.getString("a");" but somthing lik [i] String a = object2.getString("0");)
2. I need 2 buttons for the 2 choices you need to make ( so considring th photo atachd, obj 1 has path 2 and 5 to choose from) that can b used everytime he makes a choice until it reaches the end.
   So in th code of the button that takes you on path 5 (considring the photo, for obj 1) JSONObject object1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("3"); (I want it to be  3 here and not 5, because its the 3rd(0-1-2-3) item in obj 1

[every obj has 4 keys/paths/values.Now considering obj 1, first 2 to be read (so we get a1 and b1 ), and the nxt 2 to choose betwen on which path you want to take(path 2 or 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCY1O.png)

```
[
  {
    "1": {
      "2": {
        "a": "a2",
        "b": "b2",
        "3":{"a":"a3",
             "b":"b3"
             "20":{},
             "21":{}
      
        },
        "4":{"a":"a4",
             "b":"b4",
              "12":{"a":"a12",
                    "b":"b12"},
              "13":{"a":"a13",
                    "b":"b13"}
              }

      },
      "5": {
        "a": "a5",
        "b": "b5",
        "15":{"a":"a15",
              "b":"b15"},
        "16":{"a":"a16"}
            
      },
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1"
    }
  }
]
```

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    ArrayList<String> userList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        initializeUserList();

        binding.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new fetchData().start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeUserList() {
        userList =  new ArrayList<>();
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,userList);
        binding.userList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    class fetchData extends Thread {
        String data = "";
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("fetching data");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            });

            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://api.npoint.io/ba77aacc0972af3c686a");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    data.append(line);
                }

                if (!data.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data.toString());
                    JSONObject object1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("1");
                    JSONObject object2 = object1.getJSONObject(v); // Access the "2" object
                    String a = object2.getString("a");
                    String b = object2.getString("b");
               //     String aa = object1.getString("a");
                //    String bb = object1.getString("b");
                    userList.add(a);
                    userList.add(b);
                 //   userList.add(aa);
                 //   userList.add(bb);

                    Log.d("obj", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });

        }
    }



}
```

I didnt see anything similar on internet to solve my problem (maybe smth like json path? but idk if it rly helps me and idk how to add it to the ANdroid Studio

Comment: Why you use variable key name for the choose actions?  If you rename "2", "3", "12", "15", "20"  to "chooseA" and rename "5", "4", "21", "13", "16" to "chooseB", will it solve your problem?

Comment: Th prob is, th json is gonna reach 1000th obj.. And it will be impossibl to keep count as i mak th obj if I hav choos a or b

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In addition to rename the choose action to a fixed key name, you can add keys like "indexA" and "indexB" to store to index value in each node